# gson cannot be resolved to a module error in module-info.java

Tags: java, maven, gson

I've created a maven project in VScode and added GSON to my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm using Java 17 and modules for the first time.

I've added "requires gson;" to my module-info.java but it reports "gson cannot be resolved to a module"
The Maven dependencies are showing the gson:2.10.1 library and I see it has been downloaded in the .m2/respository folder.

My module-info.java:

```
module mypackage {
    // needed for JavaFX
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    //requires javafx.swing;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;

    // needed for HTTP
    requires unirest.java;

    // needed for JSON
    requires gson;
    requires java.sql;

    // needed for JavaFX
    opens mypackage to javafx.fxml;

    exports mypackage;
}
```

Obviously in the class where I import Gson, GsonBuilder, etc it fails with "The type com.google.gson.Gson is not accessible".

Any ideas? Go gentle I'm not a programmer by trade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module name of Gson is `com.google.gson` (see also the [README](https://github.com/google/gson#minimum-java-version) or the [Javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/module-summary.html)). Therefore you should use:

```java
requires com.google.gson;
```

But most likely you will also have to open your packages to Gson because it uses reflection to access the fields of your classes:

```java
opens mypackage to com.google.gson;
```

(Also for the recent Gson versions you don't have to add `requires java.sql` anymore.)

Comment: Thanks, changing the requires to com.google.gson; worked.  I thought I'd tried that before but looks like I might have been a little impatient, it takes a few seconds for the error to disappear.